# why do we include CA Bundle with paypal IPN request

Tags: paypal, certificate, paypal-ipn

I don't understand why do we need to include a certificate when posting back data to paypal when using IPN payments.

What does this certificate do? and what resources do I need to read to understand the meaning of CA bundles and how are they used?

Answer (score 0):

A certificate is basically a vessel for a [public key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate). It is issued by a trusted authority to an entity so that it can be used to establish identity over the internet. So, if Verisign issues you a certificate for the domain name `www.example.com` then Verisign trusts that you are the person who owns that domain name and will use one of its certs to 'sign' your [certificate signing request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) and give you a certificate.

Usually, instead of just one cert signing everything, there is a [Root certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_certificate) and one or more intermediate certificates. This is called the [chain of trust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_trust). As long as the chain starts at a well-known root and ends in your certificate, you have proven your identity over the internet. The CA bundle is the root cert + all the intermediate certs. Often when the party you are connecting to does not have the required intermediate certs, you need to include the CA bundle along with your domain cert.